# How much of Visual Studio is managed and how much of it is unmanaged in 2008 and 2010?

Tags: visual-studio

If anyone knows how much of Visual Studio is turning into managed code?

I read in [some sites](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vstsprerelease/thread/6c7ad1c0-19fb-48d0-b453-60e9b29012ee) that most of the Visual Studio 2010 is managed, compared to older versions where it was mostly native.

Is MS finally showing some premise for writing their first line of business apps with C# and .NET? (Thus proving that .NET is more than capable for doing large scale performant applications)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually in 2010 a lot of it is managed.

- As mentioned above, the editor is fully managed.
- The new shell (UI, toolbars, documents, menus, some toolwindows) is managed.
- A good chunk of the language services (C#, VB) is managed.
- All new C# and VB IDE features are managed (Call Hierarchy, Highlight References, Navigate To, Generate  - From Usage).
- Most (if not all) of F# is managed.
- The build system (MSBuild) is managed.
- A big chunk of debugger is managed (toolwindows, exception assistant, data tips, etc).
- Most of Team System features (team test, team data, etc) is managed.
- The entire TFS (Team Foundation Server - source control, bug tracking, builds, documents, etc) - is all managed.
- ASP.NET and tools is managed.
- Windows Forms designer is managed.
- WPF and Silverlight designers are managed.
- Various designers (such as resource) are managed.
- The XML editor and XSD features are all managed.
- IntelliTrace (back-in-time debugger) is managed.
- Parallel Tools (parallel extensions) are managed.
- A lot of other functionality which I can't now remember is surely managed.
- And last, but not least, the About Box is now managed!

So I guess the question should be what's still native ;)

Comment: Thanks, just a question. All of this is done in VS2010 from VS2008?

Comment: Well, a lot of it was managed in VS 2008. But a lot is new (Editor, Shell, IDE features, F#, Architecture Explorer, IntelliTrace etc).

Answer (score 3):

The code editor is now based on WPF in VS 2010. That alone gives us the ability to easily create new plugins in a way not possible under the old COM model.

Answer (score 1):

For me the most interesting part is the new WPF-based editor. But it buggy and a bit slow even in Beta2. But If Microsoft sort out this performance problems i'll be happy. Because from VS2010 we can have strong confidence in .NET (since microsoft as the creator have confidence in .NET)

Comment: But it's MUCH MUCH better than Beta 1. I had to set Windows to the Classic theme in Beta 1 just to make it usable. :o

Comment: Yes i agree with you. But we should compare it not with previous beta but with one from VS2008. because if it will not stable, robust those extension abilities will be useless.